# How to authenticate with new PnP core beta

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, office-dev-pnp

With the classic PnP you could authenticate with something like this:

```
public static ClientContext GetAppContext(string siteUrl, string appId, string appSecret, string appName, OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager authManager, ILogger logger)
{
    var ctx = authManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, appId, appSecret);
    var ere = ctx.GetAccessToken();
    ctx.RequestTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
    var web = ctx.Web;
    var site = ctx.Site;

    ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.UserAgent = $"NONISV|KK|{appName}/1.0";
    };

    ctx.Load(web);
    ctx.Load(site);
    ctx.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry(3, logger);
    return ctx;
}
```

We want to use this with the newer versions of Azure functions so we are looking on the new beta build on .NET Core. However we cant find any samples where we can authenticate with ClientId, Secret and TenantId. Any pointers? We can see there is something in the documentation, but it is pretty hard to understand how to use it. All input is appreciated.

https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/api/PnP.Core.Auth.OnBehalfOfAuthenticationProvider.html#PnP_Core_Auth_OnBehalfOfAuthenticationProvider__ctor_System_String_System_String_SecureString_Func_System_String__

Comment: Same problem :(